# Status bar hidden while playing video using MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Iam playing to recorded video using MPMoviePlayer and with a customized overlay on it. Now, I am unble to show the status bar while playing the video. I think it is due to setting the control style to None for movie player.

Here is my code:

```
        self.moviePlayerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:destPath_str]];
        self.moviePlayerVC.moviePlayer.controlStyle= MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
        self.moviePlayerVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
        self.moviePlayerVC.moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleNone;
        [self.moviePlayerVC.view addSubview:[self overLayOnVideoPlayerScreen]];
        [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayerVC.view];
```

Give me any suggestions :)

Comment: I have the same issue. Don't think it is related to controls. Any progress?